# Insert JSON API result into SQLite db - Flask

Tags: python, json, sqlite, flask

I have this method:

```
def getHistoricRates():
    """ Here we have the function that will retrieve the historical rates from fixer.io, since 1999 """
    rates = []
    response = urlopen('my_api_key')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float) 
    rates_from_rdata = rdata.get('rates', {})
    for rate_symbol in ['USD', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'AUD', 'JPY', 'SEK', 'NOK']:
        try:
            rates.append(rates_from_rdata[rate_symbol])
            with open('usio.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(rdata, outfile)
            history_currency = json.load(open('usio.json'))
            db = sqlite3.connect("usio.sql")
            c = db.cursor()
        #curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE rates(
        #    currency TEXT NOT NULL,
        #    rate REAL NOT NULL,
        #    )''')
        except KeyError:
            logging.warning('rate for {} not found in rdata'.format(rate_symbol)) 
            pass

    return rates
```

This stores the result into a `json` file `with open('usio.json', 'w') as outfile`, I need to take this `json` result into a SQLite db, I do have an sql file, `db = sqlite3.connect("usio.sql")` but then, I get confused, I've seen lots of tutorials, but I still don't get the point to what I need.

1.- Is there a clear way to create the table with rows and columns on the fly on SQLite for this purpose?

2.- How can I continue my logic, after I do connect with my sql file, so I can store the `json.dump` result there?

This is more or less my table structure, is pretty simple:

```
curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE rates(
        currency TEXT NOT NULL,
        rate REAL NOT NULL,
        )''')
```

Which is currently commented into my code.

The json response looks like this:

```
success true
timestamp   1535180947
base    "EUR"
date    "2018-08-25"
rates   
AED 4.272855
AFN 84.510584
ALL 125.782694
AMD 559.27321
... more currencies with their rates
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Why would you create a table "on the fly"?

Comment: Well, just asking if I can do it on the very same function which retrieves the data from the API, if not then that's ok, but I'd like to create that in a more or less automated fashio on the application, if possible of course

Comment: Why are you writing to a file only to immediately read that same file? That seems pretty pointless.

Comment: Well, couldn't find any example on how to write the result into db without storing it first

Comment: If you have cleaned json data available. You can read that data into a Pandas DataFrame using to_json() function. And this dataframe can be pushed into Sqlite db using to_sql() method available for Pandas dataframe. It will be on the fly. Try reading those documentation for better use.